# How to populate a List which has a class within a class

Tags: c#

JSON:

```
{
    "Col1": "John",
    "Col2": "Doe",
    "Col3Combined": [
        {
            "Col3": "12",
            "Col4Combined": [
                {
                    "Col4": "156-345"
                }
            ],
            "Col5Combined": [
                {
                    "Col5": "792-098"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Col1": "Mike",
    "Col2": "Keller",
    "Col3Combined": [
        {
            "Col3": "12",
            "Col4Combined": [
                {
                    "Col4": "145-394"
                }
            ],
            "Col5Combined": [
                {
                    "Col5": "156-323"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Col3": "15",
            "Col4Combined": [
                {
                    "Col4": "909-203"
                }
            ],
            "Col5Combined": [
                {
                    "Col5": "121-444",
                    "Col5": "134-232"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

C# classes:

```
public class Col4Combined
{
    public string Col4 { get; set; }
}

public class Col5Combined
{
    public string Col5 { get; set; }
}

public class Col3Combined
{
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
    public List<Col4Combined> Col4Combined { get; set; }
    public List<Col5Combined> Col5Combined { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public List<Col3Combined> Col3Combined { get; set; }
}
```

I am doing the following:

```
List<RootObject> lr = new List<RootObject>();
lr.Add(new RootObject
{
    Col1 = "test",
    Col2 = "test2",
    Col3Combined = new List<Col3Combined>(); //but then how do I populate it?
}
);
```

How can I populate `Col3Combined` in the list above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the collection initializer for that:

```
lr.Add(new RootObject
{
    Col1 = "test",
    Col2 = "test2",
    Col3Combined = new List<Col3Combined>
    {
        new Col3Combined(),
        // And others
    }
});
```

Basically you can do it all the way:

```
var lr = new List<RootObject>
{
    new RootObject
    {
        Col3Combined = new List<Col3Combined>
        {
            new Col3Combined
            {
                Col4Combined = new List<Col4Combined>
                {
                    new Col4Combined { Col4 = "some string" }
                },
                Col5Combined = new List<Col5Combined>
                {
                    new Col5Combined { Col5 = "some other string" }
                }
            }
            // And others
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So would `Col3 = "test3", Col4Combined = new List<Col4Combined() { }...` etc.?

Comment: @Si8 - exactly :)

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. Can you please have an example with populating dummy data also?

Comment: nevermind, I think I got it. I will test it out now... :)

Comment: Just needed a little sample and I am on my merry way... thanks! Will be able to accept in 7 mins

Comment: Just one quick question, can I use a forloop inside the list to add multiple of each?

Comment: @Si8 Yes but not inside the initializer. First create and then once you initialized you can just access the property and add

Comment: So let's say I have something like this: `string[] k = new string[] { "part1", "part2", "part3"};` I want to add a new `Col4` inside `Col4Combined` for each k, how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @Si8 - that is a followup question. If you try and fail to find the solution then you can post a new question. If you comment me I will be happy to help

Comment: Awesome thing. I was going to right now. Thank you. Let me ask a new question.

Comment: I had some food and i understood what you meant... I created the subkey before in a new list for the specific key and added it to the main json... it's working now. Thanks.